# Why did Vladimir Putin order a pullout from Syria in late 2017?

Tags: russian-federation, international-relations, syria, vladimir-putin

Vladimir Putin ordered pullout of Russian troops from Syria. Why such a decision?
 Russia had entered Syria to ensure that Bashar-Al-Assad remain in power and the West do not put a puppet in power?
It would have been logical to let the troops stay in Syria till Assad ensures stability in the volatile country

Comment: Some Russian troops **will** stay on two permanent bases in Syria. Also, do not take Putin's word for granted, the pullout may take a very long time, or not happen at all if Assad still needs active military support. https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/26186/putins-2016-announcement-withdrawal-of-russian-troops-from-syria

Comment: Also, it's not the first declared "pullout", if I recall correctly.

Comment: @mustaccio The first pullout was to increase the odd of success of a negotiation were the USA were asked to provide a list of moderate rebels. The russians claimed they failed to do so. So they send back their troops in order to get a military victory.

Comment: Has anyone else noted the pun of Putin doing a Pullout?

Comment: @xrorox : "send back" in this comment of yours contradicts "I don't think they did withdrawn troops." in your own comment here: https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/26216/15897 , written 15 hours ago...

Comment: @Evargalo True, I knew why they planned to withdrawn troops, why they cancelled, but not if they actually follow through. As the answer there seemed well informed, I took his words at face value.  Actually, the fact that did act on it or not in march 2016, is not really important. Talks failed, so military victories were a prerequisite to end the war.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Surely, that has to do with the previous announcement of such withdrawal made as early as 2016. See, for example, [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/26186/putins-2016-announcement-withdrawal-of-russian-troops-from-syria). Also, such possibilty was actively discussed in Russian media, and by Russian officials in a couple of previous months (for example, [here](http://www.interfax.ru/world/583519), [here](https://ru.reuters.com/article/topNews/idRUKBN1DN1HO-ORUTP) and [here](https://www.gazeta.ru/army/2017/11/27/11011310.shtml)).

But, just as in 2016, Russia is definitely **not going to** withdraw **all** the troops from Syria. At the very least, the military bases in Tartus and Hmeymim are leased for another 49 years.

The Kremlin's [official site](http://kremlin.ru/events/president/news/56351) cites Putin's speech on that matter (the translation is mine):

> Here [in Syria] we've established and will make use on the permanent basis of the two basing points: Tartus and Hmeymim. And if the terrorists will ever raise their heads again, we shall strike such a blow they haven't even seen before.

So this announcement should only result in decreasing in the number of Russian troops in Syria, which seems quite natural after the successful campaign of 2017. On 12/12/17 only the following units are ordered to leave Syria: 23 jets, 2 Ka-52 helicopters, a special forces squad, a mine clearing squad, military hospital and military police (see [here](https://lenta.ru/news/2017/12/11/nachalos)).

Comment: As an addendum, Daesh lost almost all his territory if not all. And the Syrian regime should win the war.  So the russians troops are no longer needed, and Putin can avoid some war propaganga from geopolitical rivals and claim a military victory right before an election year. After all, you can't wage war withouth killing civilians or enduring losses. The americans have proved it again and again.

Comment: @xrorox Well, in fact Daesh is still there having intensive clashes against an-Nusra (which is quite nice from almost any point of view). But, anyway, the current rumours are that the number of Russian troops and units will be reduced by half. So it's expected to be a very significant reduction, but not a true withdrawal by any means.

Comment: True, but you could not expect a true withdrawal. The russians don't have many bases in the region and they still need to shield Damas. If they leave and the US take down Assad one way or the other, they will have fought for nothing.

Comment: @xrorox Moreover, there are persistent rumours that Russia is going to establish another military bases in nearby countries, so overall Russian presence in the region will even grow.

Comment: Yeah, Irak and Iran are likely candidates, maybe Egypt but not right now.  I wonder if they did not already got air bases in Iran.

Comment: @xrorox Iran is particularly against any permanent foreign military presence, so it's highly unlikely Russia will ever have a base in Iran.

Answer (score 14):

While it is impossible to answer what Putin may be thinking, the obvious reason would be the imminent presidential elections of 2018. While a few years ago the majority of Russians supported intervention, deteriorating economy and increasing death tolls turned the public opinion around. E.g. a [poll](https://themoscowtimes.com/news/russians-appetite-for-syrian-campaign-wanes-58858) a few months ago  showed that half of the population supported withdrawal (with 30% supporting ongoing conflict).

Edit: As pointed out in the other answer, ordering to withdraw does not equal actually withdrawing. Every [presidential] election cycle in Russia there are a bunch of loud presidential orders and instructions regarding whatever the hottest topic in society is, be it reigning in banks, freezing utility bills or raising pensions. After elections are over, those orders are rarely followed.

Comment: Who cares about the elections, Putin will win 90+% anyway no matter what he's doing.

Comment: @Bregalad In the last election, he got 64%. Also, you seem to think that in a non-democracy, the opinion of the people is irrelevant. But this isn't the case. Even an adamant dictator needs support from the population, and people getting increasingly unhappy with the government can pose a problem. If Putin can eliminate that source of problems without major costs, he will.

Comment: From what I gather, the Russians are divided on Putin. On one hand they dislike Putin on the way he runs the country, being authoritarian. On the other hand, they are exceedingly happy the way he keeps the West at bay. So it is difficult for them to take only one stand.

Comment: @ShantanuHebbar : plot twist: the Russian people happen to be around 150 million individuals who do not necessary all agree on every subject, especially in politics.

Comment: @ShantanuHebbar - actually Russia experienced tremendous economic growth under Putin, as for the negative development since 2014, I'd say most Russians realize that's not really Putin's fault, but punishment for Russia upholding its sovereignty and defending its national interests. They also probably realize that if Russia kneeled to the US the damages will be even greater than those from sanctions, 95% of the Russians don't want another Yeltsin or Gorbachev, they rather do with less than bow down to their country's arch nemesis. Which is also why "pro western" parties do very bad in Russia.

Comment: @ShantanuHebbar Actually, just last month there was a poll in Russia, in which about 80% respondents said that Russia *requires*, not just alright with, "a strong hand", i.e. authoritarianism. Of course there is some opposition, there always is, but they aren't the audience targeted by Putin.

Comment: @dtech The growth was a) sustained purely by inflated oil (and gas) prices, not any intelligent policies and b) pretty pathetic compared to the growth of actually rapidly developing countries. And the damage from sanctions by Russian government upon Russian population is by orders of magnitude greater than damage from Western sanctions upon Russian government. But this is not the place for such discussions.

Comment: @Alice do you realize that oil and gas combined have never exceeded 15% of the GDP?

Comment: @Alice Don't mean to paranoid, but results of the official surveys often diverge from actual country's situation or public opinion of citizens (not necessarily worldwide but in Russia for sure).

Comment: @Alice [that poll](https://www.levada.ru/2017/12/11/17232/) had 40% saying that Russia requires "a strong hand" and 38% saying that they are okay with "strong hand" government in situations like the one Russia has right now. It's not quite the same as 80% wanting an Emperor Putin. The same poll has 49% of respondents blaming Putin personally for all problems of the country.

Answer (score 3):

Putin has still an [airbase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khmeimim_(air_base)) in Syria and is able to submit ground soldiers within [hours](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-mideast-crisis-syria-putin/russia-can-make-powerful-syria-military-comeback-in-hours-putin-idUSKCN0WJ1D4). Because the enemies of Assad are weakend, it is not necessary to have a large number of soldiers in foreign countries. The goal was to ensure that Assad remains in his position, not to gain total control. Thus it is cheaper to take a part back.

Comment: There is also a naval base in Tartous. Do you have any source to sustain that defeating IS was Russia's primary goal in Syria ? Putin made a lot of claims about fighting against terrorism, but under "terrorism" he included all the enemies of Bachar El-Assad (IS, Al-Nusra, Free Syrian Army, Kurds...), repetedly refusing to make any distingo between them. Most of these enemies, if weakened (which is not even the case for Kurds), are far from destroyed.

Comment: This is true :) But there is also no real difference despite the Kurds. Most of Assads soldiers/enemies were just mercenaries. If the opposition was paying better they swapped forth and back. There is no real reason to distinguish them if you want to save the only hope for stability in the region.

Comment: Your last comment has an even more surprising statement. Any source about your mercenaries switching side ? There may have been some militia changing side at some point, but the soldiers who defected from SAA to join the rebels in 2012-3 could not come back to Assad or they would be executed as traitors, I haven't heard of any Hezbullah member defecting to fight against Assad, nor about FSA paying any mercenaries. IS fighters switching sides seems no less unlikely.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_fighters_in_the_Syrian_and_Iraqi_Civil_Wars was always and will always be the same :/ Why else they would kill each other? After IS got access to money they hired whatever they could get. Like in every modern conflict :)

Comment: And btw, your statement that "the enemies of Assad are defeated" still seems an inappropriate answer. While Assad's regime is much more steady than in years 2011-15, he barely controls 60% of the country and has to fight on three fronts. https://syria.liveuamap.com/

Comment: Second sentence from your wiki link: *The conflicts are sectarian, with foreign Sunnis fighting for the Syrian opposition and the Islamic State, foreign Shias fighting for the Syrian government, and foreign leftists fighting for the People's Protection Units.* is actually a strong argument against any fighter changing side.

Comment: "25-30,000" foreign terrorist mercenaries. The discussion whether mercenaries stay till the end on one side is rather silly. But there is some gossip that even russian mercenaries helped Assad and also some europeans helping the Kurds aso http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/world-news/i-simply-love-killing-outed-11354129… they don't care about the side (he said so) :D

Comment: @Evargalo `the soldiers who defected from SAA to join the rebels in 2012-3 could not come back to Assad or they would be executed as traitors` There was already a ton of amnesties about them. In fact, many Sunnis already switched sides, because everyone knows that support for a prevailing side is much safer and will pay off.